im looking to create a MEV bot on solana, but i need help
ive recently noticed this wallet:
https://solscan.io/account/93gMmYdHDwK9JS8Xnj8ST4tG1HdpeDeS18tjkTLNn2xG#transactions
making hundereds of sol every single day. I found out that i need to be validator to be able to mev people but idk where to start. can i use original validator from solana or do i have to build mine? if i can use that, how do i get the transaction info like mint address, amount, slippage. Thank you for answer!
